# Exception: First select an active worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I just started working with Google Apps Script so don't be to harsch^^.
My function: "GetData" works flaweless if triggered manually, but if my time based trigger activates it I get an error via email.

the error:

> Exception: First select an active worksheet.

```
function pullData() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var lr = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
 var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy")
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('XXXX');
 var range = ss.getRange('C32').getValue();

 sheet.getRange('A' + lr).setValue(date);
 sheet.getRange('B' + lr).setValue(range);
 sheet.getRange('A32').setValue('done');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What many sheets have your spreadsheet? Do you want to get the first sheet or another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issues

When you use a **time-trigger** for a particular function that interacts with your spreadsheet file, it is **not** recommended to use **active** sheets.

---

**Issue 1:**

**Replace**:

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

**with**

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");`

Assuming you have multiple sheets in your spreadsheet file.

If you use:

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow()` you get the last row with content of the active sheet. How can you be sure that the active sheet is the sheet that you are interested in getting its last row number?

---

**Issue 2:**

Here:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('XXXX');
 var range = ss.getRange('C32').getValue();
```

again, you don't define the particular sheet you want to work with.

**Replace** that **with**:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('XXXX').getSheetByName("Sheet2");
 var range = ss.getRange('C32').getValue();
```

---

### Solution

Modify `Sheet1` and/or `Sheet2` with the names of the sheets in your particular scenario/problem.

```
function pullData() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var lr = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
 var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy")
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('XXXX').getSheetByName("Sheet2");
 var range = ss.getRange('C32').getValue();

 sheet.getRange('A' + lr).setValue(date);
 sheet.getRange('B' + lr).setValue(range);
 sheet.getRange('A32').setValue('done');
}
```

---

### References:

[getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with your code is that `getLastRow()` is a method of Class Sheet but `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` returns a Spreadsheet object not Sheet object

Similar to what was suggested in the previous answer, replace

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

by

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Please bear in mind that the first sheet will be returned. If you need to return a different sheet, instad of `getActiveSheet()` you could use `getSheetByName(name)` or you could  `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()` to get a collection of Sheet objects then you could a bracket notation `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[2]` to get a Sheet object based on its position.

Another situation that might be a problem is that the `getRange(a1Notation)` from the Spreadsheet Class when using a range reference withoug specifing the sheet name will get the corresponging cell of the first sheet. If you are looking to work with the first sheet, this will not be a problem.